# CGI log file empty

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

I feel like a real novice with this question, but sometimes huge experience can have a bad day.

I have this CGI script for file upload in file chunks. It is correctly uploading my files just fine, however I can't get a log file to write log data even though it used to work perfectly. The log file is zero bytes.

I added a couple of lines to greatly simplify debug at the start of the script. They are listed below. They open a new log file, write a simple line of text, then close it.

I figured it can't be a flush problem as I'm closing the file. It must be opening the file because the file exists, just zero bytes. It must be running the CGI script, because my file does not upload otherwise. And it has permission to write to `/tmp`, as the file is created. Also there are no errors in `/etc/httpd/logs/errorlog`

```
open(LOGFILE, ">", "/tmp/olss2.log") or die "Can't open log file: $!";
$| = 1;
print LOGFILE "New Log Entry Started";
close LOGFILE;
```

Comment: What happens when you change `>` to `>>` in _all_ cases of `open LOGFILE...`?

Comment: as raina said: dont > if you want to append to file :) > will overwrite.. only >> appends.. i will advice to set $| = 1; as one of the first vars in you script.. furthermore i advice to declare a filehandle with $ e.g. $LOGFILE because it´s easier to pass around..

Comment: No change in symptoms with these suggestions.  It is really weird.   $| = 1;  my $LOGFILE;
open ($LOGFILE, ">>", "/tmp/olss2.log") or die "Couldn't open olss.log for writing: $!";
print $LOGFILE "New Log Entry Started\n";
close $LOGFILE;

Comment: Ok, I think it is an interaction with other processing on the server.  I have the fuse filesystem in user space.  I also have tomcat running on a different port. Still don't know but that is my guess right now.

Comment: `$|=1` probably isn't doing what you think it is -- it only applies to the currently [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html)ed filehandle (see [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)). You're enabling autoflush for STDIN/STDOUT. I don't think it's a flush problem either, but you could try something like `{my $oldfh = select LOGFILE;$|=1;select $oldfh};`

Comment: try changing the second comma in the open statement to a concatenation - open(LOGFILE, ">"."/tmp/olss2.log") or die "Can't open log file: $!"; Another test you could do is place text in the file before running the script to check if the open statement is causing a new file to be created, but failing before content is being written or the file closed. I'd also write more than one line in as a test just to see if the last line is not being written, for some reason.

Comment: All good suggestions, thank you all, but I found the real problem!  My disk partition was filling up, so it would always open a file, never write to it, then not be able to close it.  So even though my logging was working, it could not flush data to disk.  Whenever you have really strange behavior always check your disk with df

Comment: Use CGI::Carp to see the failures instead of resorting only to filesystem logging during the debugging stage. The error about the filesystem was most likely being hidden by the fact that the only way you typically see errors in CGI programs is through logging to the filesystem. Another dev trick is to log them to a memory based filesystem but that has a whole additional set of failure conditions.